# fill data in dropdown box as per previous dropdown box data selected in aspnet mvc 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm buildin' an employee registration form in aspnet mvc, i have fields like "School" list in 1 dropdown box and "Department" list another, problem is i want to show Department list on change of School list, i have done followin' code:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeCreate()
{
   var getSchool = SchoolRepository.GetAllSchoolsInArray();//this gets school_id as value and school_name as text for dropdown box
   ViewData["SchoolsList"] = getSchool;

   return View();
}
```

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EmployeeCreate()
{
   _employeeRepository.CreateEmployee(employeeToCreate);
   _employeeRepository.SaveToDb();
}
```

Here is the View

```
Html.DropDownList("SchoolLists")
Html.DropDownList("DepartmentLists")
```

now, how do i get the departments of selected school in dropdown boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate the Departments list based on the value of the selected School when this value changes you could use javascript and AJAX. So you setup a controller action which would return the departments for a given school:

```
public DepartmentsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? schoolId)
    {
        var departments = _depsRepo.GetDepartmentsForSchool(schoolId);
        return Json(departments);
    }
}
```

Once you have this controller you could use jQuery to register a change event of the schools drop down:

```
$(function() {
    $('#SchoolList').change(function() {
        var schoolId = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON('/departments/index', { schoolId: schoolId }, 
            function(departments) {
                var depsList = $('#DepartmentLists');
                depsList.empty();
                $(departments).each(function(i, department) {
                    // Id and Name used here should be properties
                    // of the department model
                    depsList.append(
                        '<option value="' + department.Id + '">' + 
                         department.Name + '</option>'
                    );
                });
        });
    });
});
```